# Is there a package on hackage with common utils/idioms from other functional(ish) languages?

Tags: haskell

F# has this great util function `(|>) a b = b a` that can really help readability for long chains of function applications. I could redefine it easily, but it's part of a class of convenience functions (another would be `tupleApply f (a, b) = f a b` that don't really belong anywhere but some file called "utils.hs". Is there a package with the "sugar" I'm looking for, or is it best practice to avoid using idioms like that?

Comment: `tupleApply` is `uncurry` and Control.Lens defines `(|>)` as `(&)`

Comment: [Here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#walk-the-line) they use analagous to `(|>)` function `(-:)`. But it looks like defined by hands.

Comment: on top of this you can find any of those functions yourself very easily by using [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de) - here is an [example for the *pipe* function](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=a+-%3E+%28a-%3Eb%29+-%3E+b)

Comment: In haskell, we use `$` or `.` for long chains. Their flipped versions are less frequently used: they are called `&` (very uncommon, from lens package ), and `>>>` (from arrows).

Comment: Thanks, all. These were incredibly helpful

Comment: As a general comment, I'd argue that what you are trying to do is inherently wrong. Programming in language X by redefining standard functions so that they match the names they have in language Y feels wrong: it will lead to programs which are not idiomatic in X. This can then lead to the temptation of writing X code by designing the code thinking in terms of Y, and then trying to shoehorn-translate the design into X. I'd advise against this.

Comment: The `base` that comes with ghc-7.10 defines `&` in [`Data.Function`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-) .

Comment: Yeah, I'd tend to agree with you, I just wanted to know where to dig up all of the utils I keep on wanting to type out. I suppose I was just thinking since they were constructs from immutable-by-default functional(ish) languages, they might be idiomatic haskell. In the end, it turns out there are plenty of synonyms for what I want, and I'll just learn those.

Comment: @chi, `>>>` is actually native to the much lighter/saner `Control.Category`, not `Control.Arrow`.

Comment: @jcc333, when different languages/language families collide, you sometimes end up needing to learn different sets of symbols for things. In Haskell, `|>` is sometimes (but not always/everywhere!) used to mean what is elsewhere called `snoc`, `pushR`, or `enqueue`. It's probably been used that way since about 2006. `$` and likely `>>>` go back to the 90s, but `&` is probably just a few years old.